# Process.Exited not reached when running in Task.Run

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I am having a problem getting the Process.Exited event to fire when I run the process using a Task.Run in a WPF app.
If this getting this Exited event is out of the questions due to the process class limitation, I would like to to update the TextBox.Text when the task is complete.
I tried ContinueWith without any luck either

```
async private void Select_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken();
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        FolderBrowserDialog diag;
        TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        Notification.Text = string.Empty;
        diag = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        var result = diag.ShowDialog();
        var istest = TestMode.IsChecked == true;

        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var path = diag.SelectedPath;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                                {
                                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                                    UseShellExecute = false,
                                    CreateNoWindow = true
                                };
                var command="ping yahoo.com";

                var process = new Process() { StartInfo = processStartInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true };
                process.Start();

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync(command);
                process.ErrorDataReceived += (p, @event) =>
                {
                    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        Notification.AppendText(String.Format("Error {0} {1}", @event.Data, Environment.NewLine));
                    }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
                };
                process.OutputDataReceived += (p, @event) =>
                {
                    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        Notification.AppendText(@event.Data + Environment.NewLine);
                    }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
                };
                process.WaitForExit();
                process.Exited += (@Sender, args) =>
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(process);
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Done");
                    process.Dispose();
                };
            });

        }

    }
```

All of the other events are getting fired without any problems.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `WaitForExit` before you subscribe `Exited` event, so thread will wait there till process exits and never subscribes the event before the process exits. When `WaitForExit` returns process is already exited, then only you subscribe `Exited` event which is never going to fire again.

So subscribe `Exited` event before you call `WaitForExit`.

```
process.Exited += (@Sender, args) =>
{
    tcs.SetResult(process);
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Done");
    process.Dispose();
};
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I actually tried that, still the event never fired.

Comment: @user3373870 Are you sure the process exited?

Comment: That's the problem, the process is not exiting.
I have to force the process (cmd.exe to exit)

Comment: @user3373870 [This should help](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bc261774-ecdb-4afd-93a6-c94c40217bb5/closing-a-command-prompt-window-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: @ Sriram Sakthivel, Using the /C argument and I had to Modify the Exited event to 
                    process.Exited += (async(@Sender, args) =>
                    {
                     tcs.TrySetResult(process);
                       await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                        {
                            Notification.AppendText("Completed");
                        }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
                        process.Dispose();
                    });